# ClojureScript : How to access an object in an Om cursor

Tags: clojurescript, om, figwheel

I'm just experimenting with Om, learning from the basic tutorial.

My program data is in a single atom : app-state.

If I put a sequence into that atom, eg.

```
(defonce app-state (atom {:things [1 2 3 4]}))
```

Then later on, in my rendering, I can get a cursor

```
(let [things (:things data)] ... )
```

and map across it :

```
(map #(* % %) things)
```

However, if I have a defrecord with a method that can return a sequence :

```
(defrecord ThingCollection [xs]
    IThingCollection
    (getSeq [this] ... ) )
```

and put THAT into the application state

```
(defonce app-state (atom {:things (->ThingCollection [1 2 3 4]})))
```

...

```
(let [things (:things data)] ... )
```

I can't do this :

```
(map #(* % %) (.getSeq things))
```

It just throws an error saying that a cursor has no method .getSeq

That makes sense. But then how can I actually get at the ThingCollection object inside the cursor? I can't find any examples of this. And nothing I've tried seems to give it to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try `(getSeq things)`.

Few notes:

1. Prefer kebab-case `get-seq` instead of `getSeq`
2. `->ThingCollection` doesn't give an object, it just gives a record. This is still immutable and roughly just a "named map".
3. Once you realize point 2, using `.method` call should look wrong because that is for dealing with JavaScript objects.